# Call function in components that are rendered by a factory component

Tags: reactjs, function, factory

I have the following problem:

- I have a react functional component A (the parent component)
- In the parent Component A, a factory component named **< Component />** creates different Components such as Component B,C,D by using plain JSON objects.

What I want to achieve:

Component B,C and D shall all implement a handlerFunction with specific code **on their own**. So the handlerFunction is not provided by the parent component, it is implemented by the Components B,C and D on their own.

I want to call the specific handlerFunction of each Component B,C, and D.

How is this possible ?

Comment: If components B, C, and D are class-based components you can pass a react ref to them to trigger imperative functions. https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: @DrewReese that is what I've tried, and it did not work. Therefor I have created this issue here.

I always got the error "refs" cannot be given in functional component. Moreover I have tried forwardRef but this did neither work.

Problem is: the Factorycomponent < Component /> renders the child components implicitly, therefor I have no idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, functional components, on their own, cannot be assigned a react ref, but you can forward the ref or pass *a* ref as a named prop.

In the class-based component example you have something like

```
class ComponentA extends Component {
  handlerFunction = () => {
    console.log("A handler function");
  };

  render() {
    return ...;
  }
}
```

and to invoke the `handlerFunction`, attach the ref and call `ref.current.handlerFunction()` in your code

```
const someFunction = () => {
  ...
  refA.current.handlerFunction();
  ...
}

...

<ComponentA ref={refA} />
```

For a functional component you can forward the ref and use the `useImperativeHandle` hook to "connect" the ref to the internal handler function

```
const ComponentB = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    handlerFunction
  }));

  const handlerFunction = () => {
    console.log("B handler function");
  };

  return ...;
});
```

and to invoke the `handlerFunction`, same thing, call `ref.current.handlerFunction()`

```
const someFunction = () => {
  ...
  refB.current.handlerFunction();
  ...
}

...

<ComponentB ref={refB} />
```

[image: Edit call-function-in-components-that-are-rendered-by-a-factory-component]

Comment: But I don't have class-based components. They are all functional.

Comment: The class-based components aren't the issue. They were for demonstration, to show that once implemented correctly the functional components have the same interface/API for invoking the function in child via react ref. Is this solution not working for you?

Comment: @Draw Reese no it does not work. I have tried that already. My assumption is that it does not work because of the factory component. The factory calls the component implicitly.

Comment: @Gutelaunetyp OK, my running code sandbox is proof invoking a function in a functional component child from a parent works. Without seeing further what you are trying to do that isn't working I'm not sure there's much more anyone can do here. Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example code snippet to demonstrate what and how you are trying to invoke functions in children components?

Comment: @Draw Reese, ok thanks. As I cannot give a good example at the moment (too much code) , I will just give you the bounty for your effort.

Thanks

Comment: @Gutelaunetyp If you do come up with an example though, feel free to ping me if you still need an assist.